# Save batch command into variable.

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a .bat script and I want to be able to execute a command which is saved in a variable without executing another .bat file. For example, `dir /l`.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
my_command = dir /L
run my_command
```

Assign the variable `my_command` with a string and then execute this string as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in batch. Try this example:

```
 @echo off&setlocal
 set "myCommand=cls&dir /l"
 %myCommand%
```

This clears the screen (`cls`) and executes `dir /l`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked as a charm... :))
I have another question if your able to help me, how i run this command as an admin??

Comment: Sorry, but I have no multiuser windows here. Imo the command name is `Runas`. :)